# Need assistence displaying value from a different private class

Tags: java

Okay, first off I am very, very new to java. For this project I need to design a program that takes a product number, an amoutn sold, calculates the total, and then displays it. However, I need to to display when I select option 2, which is a seperate private class, to be honest I don't even know where to begin. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Attempt1
{
//method to pause until a key is pressed
public static void pause() 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        System.out.print("Press <Enter> to continue..."); 
        System.in.read(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.printf("Error %s%c\n",e.getMessage(),7);
    }
}//end pause

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //variables to capture keyboard input
    Scanner keyBd = new Scanner( System.in );
    char selection;
    //int selection;

    do{//display menu
        System.out.println("\n--------------");
        System.out.println("Retail Sales\n");
        System.out.println("1. Enter Products Sold");
        System.out.println("2. Display Total Retail Sales");
        System.out.println("3. Exit\n");
        System.out.print  ("Selection: ");

        //get menu selection
        selection = keyBd.next().charAt(0);
        //selection = keyBd.nextInt();

        //process menu selection
        switch (selection){
            case '1':
                enterProducts();
                break;
            case '2':
                displaySales();
                break;
            case '3':               
                //recognize as valid selection but do nothing
                break;
            default :
                //System.out.printf("%c\n",7);
                System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
        }//end switch

    }while( selection != '3');

}//end main()

private static void enterProducts()
{
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

    int product,quantity;
    double total = 0.00;

    System.out.print("Enter product #(1-5)(0 to stop): ");
    product=inp.nextInt();

    while(product !=0)
        {
        System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
        quantity=inp.nextInt();
    switch( product ){
    case 1:total+=quantity*2.98;
    break;
    case 2:total+=quantity*4.50;
    break;
    case 3:total+=quantity*3.98;
    break;
    case 4:total+=quantity*4.49;
    break;
    case 5:total+=quantity*6.87;
    break;
    default:System.out.println("Invalid Product Number");
    System.out.println("Product Number Does not Exist");

    if(product<0 && product>=6)
      {
    System.out.print("Enter product #(1-5)(0 to stop): ");
    product=inp.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
    quantity=inp.nextInt();
      }
    break;
    }
    System.out.print("Enter product #(1-5)(0 to stop): ");
    product=inp.nextInt(); 
    }

    pause();    
    }
private static void displaySales()
{
    System.out.println( "The total retail value was: " + total );
    pause();    
}
```

}//end MenuDemo

Comment: I don't see any private class here.. Can you explain little further what's the problem with your code?

Comment: Basically, all I need is for when I run the program, and I use the second option off the "menu" , for it to display the total from the first. If that helps at all.

Comment: Remember to indent all code with 4 spaces in front; it looks like your last line wasn't indented properly. ("}//end MenuDemo")

Comment: There is no issue with homework help. As long as your question shows evidence of having tried to solve your problem then we're all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm for improving your code:

1. At the beginning of your your main add a variable `total` and initialize it with 0: `double total=0;`
2. Change the `enterProducts` method's return type to double: `private static double enterProducts()` and return the local variable `total` at the end from this method after the call to `pause`: `return total;`
3. In the case for the input of `1` add the returned value from `enterProducts` to the current value of `total` (it's the `total` inside your main): `total += enterProducts();`
4. Add to the method `displaySales` an double argument: `private static void displaySales(double total)` and change the call to it in the main's case for `2` to `displaySales(total);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `private` *method*. You could pass the total like so:

```
private static void displaySales(double total) {
...
```

`total` is defined in `enterProducts` but not in the `main` method where the loop is displayed, so you could return this:

```
double enterProducts() {
   ...
   return total;
}
```

so that you can pass it to `displaySales`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that you're trying to access a local variable, declared in the static enterProducts() method, inside of the static displaySales() method.

The code below solves that "problem".

With that being said, I recommend that you work through some Java tutorials to understand why the code now works... Have a look at [Variable Scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm).

```
public class Attempt1
{
//use a static variable to store the total  
static double total = 0.00;

//method to pause until a key is pressed
public static void pause() 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        System.out.print("Press <Enter> to continue..."); 
        System.in.read(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.printf("Error %s%c\n",e.getMessage(),7);
    }
}//end pause

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //variables to capture keyboard input
    Scanner keyBd = new Scanner( System.in );
    char selection;
    //int selection;

    do{//display menu
        System.out.println("\n--------------");
        System.out.println("Retail Sales\n");
        System.out.println("1. Enter Products Sold");
        System.out.println("2. Display Total Retail Sales");
        System.out.println("3. Exit\n");
        System.out.print  ("Selection: ");

        //get menu selection
        selection = keyBd.next().charAt(0);
        //selection = keyBd.nextInt();

        //process menu selection
        switch (selection){
            case '1':
                enterProducts();
                break;
            case '2':
                displaySales();
                break;
            case '3':               
                //recognize as valid selection but do nothing
                break;
            default :
                //System.out.printf("%c\n",7);
                System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
        }//end switch

    }while( selection != '3');

}//end main()

private static void enterProducts()
{
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

    int product,quantity;

    System.out.print("Enter product #(1-5)(0 to stop): ");
    product=inp.nextInt();

    while(product !=0)
        {
        System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
        quantity=inp.nextInt();
    switch( product ){
    case 1:total+=quantity*2.98;
    break;
    case 2:total+=quantity*4.50;
    break;
    case 3:total+=quantity*3.98;
    break;
    case 4:total+=quantity*4.49;
    break;
    case 5:total+=quantity*6.87;
    break;
    default:System.out.println("Invalid Product Number");
    System.out.println("Product Number Does not Exist");

    if(product<0 && product>=6)
      {
    System.out.print("Enter product #(1-5)(0 to stop): ");
    product=inp.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
    quantity=inp.nextInt();
      }
    break;
    }
    System.out.print("Enter product #(1-5)(0 to stop): ");
    product=inp.nextInt(); 
    }

    pause();    
    }
private static void displaySales()
{
    System.out.println( "The total retail value was: " + total );
    pause();    
}
}//end MenuDemo
```